# Android - Cannot make a static reference to a non static method

Tags: android, multithreading

I refactoring my threads in order to avoid memory leaks, and I got 2 errors regarding handler and startActivityForResult being called  from within the thread ( dealing with GoogleDrive)

I have in my DownloadActivity :

public class DownloadActivity extends Activity {
        ....
        private void getFolderId(){
        getFolderIdThread = new GetFolderIdThread();
        getFolderIdThread.start();
    }

```
    private static class GetFolderIdThread extends Thread {
    private Boolean mRunning = false;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mRunning = true;

                    fResultList = new ArrayList<File>();
            Files f1 = mService.files();
            Files.List request = null;
            aFolderId = null;
            do {
                try  {
                    request = f1.list();
                    String aQuery = "'root' in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and title='"+ aFolderName + "'";
                    request.setQ(aQuery);                       
                    FileList fileList = request.execute();
                    fResultList.addAll(fileList.getItems());
                    request.setPageToken(fileList.getNextPageToken());
                } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                    startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);  <=  THIS RAISES THE ERROR
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    if (request != null){
                        request.setPageToken(null);
                    }
                }
            } while (request.getPageToken() !=null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

            if (fResultList.size() == 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "cannot find the training folder at root level");
                Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(); <=  THIS RAISES THE ERROR
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("msgKey", DownloadActivity.NO_TRAININGS_FOLDER);
                           msg.setData(bundle);
                           handler.sendMessage(msg);    <=  THIS RAISES THE ERROR   
            } else {
                File folder = fResultList.get(0);
                aFolderId =  folder.getId();
                getFolderContents();  <=  THIS RAISES THE ERROR
        }
    }
    public void close() {
        mRunning = false;
    }
}
```

I have the handler defined in my activity

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        ...
        }
    }
```

and the onActivityResult

```
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
                    ....
                    break;
             }
    }
```

what are my options to bypass this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GetFolderIdThread class is static and a static nested class cannot reference non-static methods and fields in the instance of the outer class that created it. Such a nested class can only access static methods and fields in your Activity. Remove static from the class definition and I think your problem will resolve.

You also need to post your call to startActivityForResult on the UI thread. Of course you should be able to use your handler for that, something like:

```
handler.post(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
    }
});
```

Make sure your thread can gracefully complete as well when you do that because it will continue to run.

Comment: I tried to write my thread as static to avoid any explicit reference to the enclosing class , so the Activity instance won't be leaked when configuration change...  I added a thread.close() in my onDestroy() method ( Activity class) ...   I need to read again some doc on the Runnable class... to better understand how leaks can be avieded

Comment: found a very good post on how to handle safely my threads and avoid memoty leaks .. http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html